# Panel abrir fechado JS

Tags: jquery, panel

Estou com o seguinte panel:

```
$(document).on('click', '.panel-heading', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
        $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
        $this.addClass('panel-collapsed');
        $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-menu-up').addClass('glyphicon-menu-down');
    } else {
        $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
        $this.removeClass('panel-collapsed');
        $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-menu-down').addClass('glyphicon-menu-up');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".btn-modal").offset().top}, 1000);
    }
});
```

A minha dúvida é: Não esto conseguindo fazer com que ele comece fechado (sem collapse), ou seja, só depois que clicar ele irá aparecer e descer, e ao clicar novamente, irá voltar para o formato fechado. O que eu faço?

Comment: Poderia colocar o HTML do Panel e, se possível, a parte `$(document).on('ready', function (){});` do seu código?

Comment: não consegues fazer um [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Pode colocar um pouco de mais código?

Answer (score 1):

Experimente colocar no `.ready` pra fechar todos panels

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.panel-heading').each(function (index) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if(!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
            $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
            $this.addClass('panel-collapsed');
            $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-menu-up').addClass('glyphicon-menu-down');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hitch, como você não postou o código completo,  percebi que você esta utilizando o [Bootstrap - Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

Se você precisa deixar todos os collapse fechados no  começo é bem simples, basta você remover a class `in` na div do conteúdo que esta visivél:

**Exemplo:** [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/uqz6ocj4/)